# COM interop, Office 2010 x64 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: com, visual-studio-2010, interop, ms-office

I just installed Office 2010 x64 on my Windows 7 x64 laptop. It already had Visual Studio 2010 on it.

Now I try to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel or something to the project, but it just can't find the project.

When I try to open a project from the website of Microsoft (a sample of Office development) Visual Studio says that that kind of project is not supported.

How is this possible? Is it a problem that I installed x64 of Office? Or is the problem Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, forgot to install Office Developer tools x64